# Why EOL error and what does it mean?

Tags: python, string, string-literals, eol

It keep coming up with `EOL while scanning string literal` but what does this mean?

This is the section it keeps calling an error:

```
if health2 <= 3:
  print ("With all the strength you have left you attack one final time to deliver the 
finishing blow. The zombie falls to the ground dead as you stand over it victorious. You can 
now continue your quest to cross the country.")
```

Comment: You are not closing the string literal at the end of the line. To get around this, use triple quotes - `""" string text ... """`

Comment: End Of Life for the zombie. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @okiharaherbst: But how can you kill that which is already dead? :P

Comment: Sounds like a fun project, OP. If you end up having a lot of these types of prints, it might be worth you time trying to save these long string messages in .txt or .xml files. This way you don't have text clogging up your code, and you wont have to recompile if you want to change what is said to the user.

Answer (score 3):

It means that your string literal is malformed.  You need to use triple quotes for a [multi-line string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals):

```
if health2 <= 3:
    print ("""With all the strength you have left you attack one final time to deliver 
the finishing blow. The zombie falls to the ground dead as you stand over it victorious. You 
can now continue your quest to cross the country.""")
```

String literals enclosed with just single quotes cannot span multiple lines.